# How could I eliminate Kerberos for passwd?

Tags: linux, kerberos, passwd

When I issue a command to change my password like this:

`sudo passwd huahsin`

The system prompt me:

`Current Kerberos password:`

I don't know what I have done to the system configuration, how could I eliminate this Kerberos thing when I change my password?

Comment: What's the output of this command show for `passwd`: `grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf`. I think you've changed your NS resolver setup.

Comment: it shows `compat lsass`. What does this means?

Comment: That means it will use an Active Directory server to authenticate. What did you do to this system? I think it makes use of a LikeWise product.

Comment: Lsass appears to be a LikeWise module: http://blog.technotesdesk.com/how-to-join-linux-server-into-active-directory-on-sbs-2008-network/

Comment: Yes, I did install likewise thing in my system, should I uninstall it? Can I just disable it?

Comment: I think you might be able to just change the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for the time being. The line can be simply this: `passwd:     files`. This will only use your local files (`/etc/passwd` & `/etc/shadow`) for passwords.

Comment: The reason why it asks for a Kerberos password is that it thinks this user should be managed by Kerberos. And the reason why it thinks so is the minimum user id set in pam.d. Find this line `pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000` in /etc/pam.d and change it to a higher number not interfering with local users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems likely to be a problem with the installation of a Active Directory (AD) integration product for authentication called LikeWise. This product is no longer available, to my knowledge.

You can read more about it her in this articled titled: [How to join Linux server into Active Directory on SBS 2008 network](http://blog.technotesdesk.com/how-to-join-linux-server-into-active-directory-on-sbs-2008-network/). It's also listed here in the Wikipedia page on [products that support SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_products_that_support_SMB) as well as here on the [Active Directory Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory).

Here are two methods for identifying this product's been setup.

#### 1. Lsass error messages

> 20111006152006:ERROR:Lsass Error [ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME]
>   Network name not found.. Failure to lookup a domain name ending in “.local” may be the result of configuring the local system’s hostname resolution (or equivalent) to use Multi-cast DN

#### 2. Modified nsswitch.conf

And these modifications to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

```
passwd: compat winbind lsass
group: compat winbind lsass
shadow: compat
```

#### Working around?

You should be able to safely leave it installed and change your Name Service Switch configuration file (`nsswitch.conf`) so that it uses just your local files for authentication.

```
passwd: files
group:  files
shadow: files
```

I also dug up this Launchpad bug that covers uninstalling LikeWise-open. There are some things that it doesn't do to revert your system when you uninstall it. They're covered in this bug along with how to manually undo the install.

- [Likewise uninstall, Lock login to system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/likewise-open/+bug/230466)

Comment: Am I require to restart any service?

Comment: @huahsin68 - No the changes should be instant. Did it not work?

Comment: Nope, the Kerbeors thing still persist. Any other solution?

Comment: @huahsin68 - see the launchpad thread I linked to. Also you need to do more then just `passwd` changes to `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: the `pam` controls are changed as well, which is where `passwd` is getting the kerberos modules.

Comment: @RickyBeam - ah that makes sense, I've never used Likewise so I'm not at all familiar with how it winds itself into your system. I'd probably just remove it unless you had a burning reason to keep it.

Comment: @slm As I read on the link you gave, I am require to leave the domain from LikeWise. And I did try it, now the kerberos thing has gone. Great help!

Comment: @huahsin68 - Great! Glad that solved your problem.

Answer (score 25):

A simple command (workaround?) that worked for me:

```
sudo -s
pam-auth-update
passwd <yourusername>
```

During [`pam-auth-update`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html), use the <kbd>space bar</kbd> to disable Kerberos authentification.

Comment: After typing shell above in my environment, `pam-auth-update` was about turning off `kerberos pam stack`. I leave a note for future reader.

thanks.